# names in a quadratic field extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Consider the quadratic field extension $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$.

1. Is there a good name to use for the parameter $d$?
2. Are there good names for $a$ and $b$ in the expression $a + b\sqrt d$?

For example, when $d = -1$ we call $a$ the real part and $b$ the imaginary part. Are there names which are used for a general quadratic extension?

Comment: If $d$ is negative, then there's no problem at all with calling $a$ the real part (though I'm sure some contrarian can invent one). If $d < -1$, then I can honestly see a problem with calling $b$ "the imaginary part," but I use such a term in my thoughts (if I used it in a comment or answer to any other question on here, they'd rip me a new one). As for $d$, the choice of that letter at least looks like it's coming close to being standard.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$.

1. If $d$ is non-zero, squarefree and congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, then $d$ is the *[discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_field#Discriminant)* of $k$ (if $d\not\equiv 1~(\operatorname{mod} 4)$ then $4d$ is the discriminant). Other than that, I'm not sure of any other *standard* name.
2. There is a canonical choice of *[power basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number_field#Power_basis)* $\lbrace 1,\sqrt{d}\rbrace$ for $k$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$. Every element of $k$ can then be expressed as a vector of two rational numbers $\mathbf{x}=\binom{a}{b}$ corresponding to the element $a+b\sqrt{d}$. In this basis then, $a$ and $b$ are just the co-ordinates of the vector $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: So for #2, how do you feel about "abscissa" and "ordinate"?

Comment: As an old-fashioned guy, I rebel against the use of “abscissa” and “ordinate”; I would use the terms first and second coordinates, or first and second entries, thinking of an $n$-tuple of things in the base as column matrices.